# Google Realtime: how to search for messages from a specific Twitter user?

Tags: twitter, google-search

For example, how would you write a search query that returns the recent updates from the Twitter user [@google](http://twitter.com/google) (and not return updates from other users that just happen to contain the word "google")? Naively, I tried `from:google`, but it doesn't have the desired effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be `site:twitter.com/google` then click on "latest" on the left sidebar.

Comment: Very nice trick. Awesome!